# TextMesh Pro unity plugin stopped working after updating Unity to 5.6 beta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

I updated Unity3D to 5.6 beta version. I had asset from store called TextMesh Pro. Now it doesn't work (no text, many NREs). Console shows:

> error CS1704: An assembly with the same name `TextMeshPro' has already
>   been imported. Consider removing one of the references or sign the
>   assembly Assets/TextMesh Pro/Plugins/TextMeshPro.dll (Location of the
>   symbol related to previous error) Assets/TextMesh
>   Pro/Plugins/Runtime-Only DLL/TextMeshPro.dll (Location of the symbol
>   related to previous error)

I did not import this twice. The changelog of Unity 5.6 says that this asset will be built in in unity, but it is not yet. Is there any workaround or fix for something like this?

Comment: Please mark an answer solving your question.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another approach which works.

Open your project folder go to `Assets` and delete the whole folder of `TextMesh Pro`.

After that go to:

`C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-UNITY_VERSION_HERE\Unity Technologies\Unity EssentialsBeta Content` and delete `TextMesh Pro.unitypackage`

After that go to Asset store and you will be able to download the latest version which works without problems on `Unity 2017.2`.

Comment: Excellent ! It did work for me. Note that i had to Restart Unity to make it work properly after installing the asset again from the asset store. +1

Comment: Worked for me, too! Thanks

Comment: Also, you need to go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com` and delete the `com.unity.textmeshpro@X.X.X` or you'll end up with the `Multiple plugins with the same name...` errors.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue by changing the import settings of TextMeshPro.dll. The workaround can be found [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/an-assembly-with-the-same-name-textmeshpro-has-already-been-imported.460786/).